# a user, that is a organizer can create conferences, but can also participante in conferences

Tags: database-design

In a conference management system, a user can create one ore many conferences. The user that creates a conference is the conference organizer. But a user can also register in a conference.

So there should be 3 entities: Conference, User, Organizer

> Conference: id, name, description
>
> Organizer: id, name, description
>
> User: id, name, username, password, email, etc

Now, do you know how the relationships between this entities should be?

This model seems difficult to understand, because a organizer can organize multiple conferences and a conference is organized by one organizer.  So should be a 1 to many relationship between organizer and conference? But then, the organizer is also a user that besides create a conference can also register in conferences. So how should be the relation between the user and the event/organizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets consider the `User - Organizer` relationship:

- An `Organizer` **is** a `User` but a `User` may or may not be an `Organizer`

This is a one-to-one (`1 - 0..1`) relationship. One way to implement it is by having the `PRIMARY KEY` of `Organizer` being a `FOREIGN KEY` that references `User`:

```
User: 
    user_id         PK
    name
    username
    password 
    email

Organizer: 
    organizer_id    PK  FK -> User 
    description
```

Now, for the `Conference`, it seems there are 2 relationships:

- An `Organizer` can organize many `Conferences`; a `Conference` has exactly one `Organizer`.

This is one-to-many relationship as you correctly noted. The common way to implement it is to have `organizer_id` in `Conference`:

```
Conference
    conference_id   PK
    organizer_id       FK -> Organizer
    name
    description
```

- The relationship between `User` and `Conference` is probably many-to-many. A User can participate in many conferences and a conference can have many participating user.

We need a junction table:

```
Participation
    conference_id   PK FK1 -> Conference
    user_id         PK FK2 -> User
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didnt understand this part "This is a 1 - 0..1 relationship", because you have user_id as a fk in the organizer table so like that its not a one to many relationship between user and organizer?

Comment: It's one-to-one. The PK of Organizer is also the FK to User. I edited a bit on that part. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks again, so the user table stays with(user_id, name, username,password, email, organizer_id) and the organizer table with (organizer_id, description) right? Also in this case do you know if its a identifying or non identifying relationship?

Comment: It's identifying - because you can't have an organizer without (being also) a user. See this answer at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships